# How can I handle Keyboard on Automation Test?

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, automation, keyboard

I've been on some automation test project now and yesterday my supervisor told me to implement a test case. This test case is on Google's service and it requires me to upload an Excel file during the test. 
I have achieved to open the Windows Dialog (it did take a while since Google did some crazy job on placing the elements and naming them) and copy my Excel file's path into the ClipBoard but I have to `CTRL + V` it to opened dialog to make it work. 
It seems like there used to be a function that can solve this problem, but it isn't available. In Java, using a thing called Robot works fine but I have to implement it in Visual Studio and using IKVM (somehow should help you use Java code in your c# code, but I couldn't make it work.) didn't work.

How can I use the keyboard while the test is running? This ultimate question is this simple but it is not that simple to find an answer. Can someone please help?

Comment: You can use keyboard_event, SendInput or SendKeys to send keyboard input programatically. This might help, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-simulate-mouse-and-keyboard-events-in-code

Comment: It doesn't work since I'm doing NUnit tests.

Comment: did you get the issue resolved?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I moved my project from Visual Studio to Katalon Studio which is Java based automation tool that has a function to upload a file (and if that doesn't work, you can create a keyword and simply do the keyboard actions on there). If you have a solution, I'd be happy to listen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You handle file uploads a bit differently with selenium.  If you want to use selenium, find the xpath or id for the file upload. Then use the below.

```
     var value= "test.csv";   //in case you run tests with multiple files you can pass in just a file name.Just create a files dir and drop your test files in there.
```

The below will create: "c:\my\path\to\files\test.xls"

```
     string filePath = string.Format(@"c:\my\path\to\files\{0}", value);
```

Then once you locate the path to the upload object, you send the file path directly to the upload call.

Click the import button to pop the upload iframe:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("ly0-layerview-import-link")).Click();
```

This is using an iFrame so you have to switch to it. The problem is the iframe id is dynamic so you need to find it first and get the id attribute and then switch to it.

```
var iframe = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//iframe[contains(@src, 'picker')]")).GetAttribute("id");
```

You will need code to switch to the iframe - If you do not have it, just create the method.

```
driver.SwitchToIframe(iframe);
```

Then upload the file-

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@type='file']")).SendKeys(filePath);
```

Comment: SendKeys might work for many upload buttons but the one I'm dealing with definetely doesn't allow you to do that.

Comment: What google service is it? again, you are not writing to the popup. you do not even click the browse button to open that dialog box. you are writing the file path to the upload input element directly which will upload the file. If you want to write to the windows object directly, look at AutoIT. It is much more difficult to use and that the way I am suggesting to upload a file.

Comment: It's the Google MyMAps. It doesn't do anythings on SendKeys to the button.

Comment: updated my answer a bit to help you. I was able to get this to work pretty easily. A few issues you were probably having. The upload dialog is in a popup that is an iframe. The iframe id is dynamic so you have to grab that first. I searched for the iframe and grabbed the id and stored it. Then I was able to switch into it each time. So this is a must. Just remember once you are done with the upload that you need to  switch back to main content.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, it works :) I definitely didn't think it was an iframe..

Answer (score 0):

you can use Selenium action chains:

```
test = driver.find_element_by_name("example")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'v')
actions.perform()
```

Comment: How can I actually use this on my code? ActionChains is not recognized.

Comment: need to import: 

from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

Comment: Uhm, I think your solution is for Java based implementations, there's nothing like Common etc. under OpenQA.Selenium, I'm using C# and Visual Studio.

Comment: Hmm maybe, but not only for java, that's module is from selenium webdriver. For python and selenium works fine.